# use column based on other column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making a shop in a game, and you can sell for 2 different currencies. I'm trying to get it so if the currency is gold in the shop it will charge your account gold and same with other currencies.

```
if (isset($_POST['slot1'])) {
$token= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['token']);
$tokenn = strip_tags($token);

$row28 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM market WHERE id='".$tokenn."");
$row27 = mysqli_fetch_array($row28);





if ($row28['currency'] >= $row28['price']) {



}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. btw I know what I have in the if () is wrong I just have that as a place holder.

In the user table there is 2 different currencies. `Upgrade Stones`, `Gold`

In the market table each item in the table has either 1 of those currencies listed under the column `currency` I want it to determine which currency is need to buy the item.

```
<table class="reg-box4">
<tr>
<th width="20%">Item</th>
<th width="20%">Stats</th>
<th width="20%">Seller</th>
<th width="20%">Price</th>
<th width="20%">Options</th>
</tr>



<?php

$result99 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM market WHERE type='".$_GET['type']."' ORDER BY time");
while($row26 = mysqli_fetch_array($result99))
{   
$idd= mysql_real_escape_string($row26['id']);
$iddd = strip_tags($idd);

?>


<tr>
<td><?php echo $row26['item']; ?>+<?php echo $row26['plus']; ?></td>
<td>Attack: <?php echo $row26['atk']; ?></br>Defence: <?php echo $row26['def']; ?></br> Health: <?php echo $row26['hp']; ?></br>Speed: <?php echo $row26['speed']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row26['user']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row26['price']; ?> <?php echo $row26['currency']; ?></td>
<form name="slot1" action="" method="post">
<td>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php  echo $iddd ;  ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="mapbutton2" value="Buy" name="slot1">
</form>
<?php
if ($row['username'] == $row26['user']) {
?>
<form name="toss" action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php  echo $iddd ;  ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="mapbutton2" value="Remove" name="toss">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</td>
</tr>



<?php

}

?>

</table>
```

Comment: You're mixing two different MySQL APIs --- Change `$token= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['token']);` to `$token= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['token']);` assuming `mysqli_*` based connection and `$con` as DB connection variable.

Comment: However, by the look of your other questions, you seem to be using `mysql_*` exclusively, therefore change `mysqli_query` to `mysql_query` and `mysqli_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_array` --- Do show full code including DB connection example to be 100% sure. Pick **one** API, not two because they do not mix. You also have a missing quote in `WHERE id='".$tokenn."");` which should read as `WHERE id='".$tokenn."'");`

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit - ON HOLD

It's not your conditional statement that is wrong, it's because you're mixing two different MySQL APIs.

Change `$token= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['token']);` to `$token= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['token']);` assuming `mysqli_*` based connection and `$link` as DB connection variable.

***However,*** by the look of your other questions, you seem to be using `mysql_*` exclusively, therefore if that is the case, you will need to change `mysqli_query` to `mysql_query` and `mysqli_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_array`

Do show full code including DB connection example in order to be 100% sure.

Pick **one** API and not two because they do not mix.

Meaning, you can't use `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions together..

You also have a missing quote in `WHERE id='".$tokenn."");`

which should read as `WHERE id='".$tokenn."'");`

Comment: That is not my problem everything works fine, I just need to know how to write out a way to make the user pay for the item with the right currency that is listed in the database

Comment: I wish you would have replied to my comments instead that I place way before this answer was posted. Did you just get notification now? @Sakai

Comment: I just got back from dinner. I'm going to explain a little better in my question.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well I'll try and think of something. If I can't, I'll just delete this. @Sakai

Comment: I might have to get back to this tomorrow. It's almost midnight here, and am having trouble concentrating. One thing I'd like to know though is how the currency is pulled in from. I notice you have POST variables, obviously taken from a form. If you could post that in your question along with any other pertinent information, that would help. @Sakai